# Conditional protases for suggestions: "Maybe if I have a read first and then we meet up later?"

Tags: syntax, linguistic-typology, conditionals

In English it's possible to use what looks like a conditional protasis in conjunction with *maybe*,  *what about*, or *how about* to informally make polite suggestions. For example, I recently got an email from a colleague which had the following sentence:

> Maybe if I can have a read first and then we catch up informally later?

This looks and feels more like a conditional protasis than an interrogative clause, even though it's not functioning as the modifier of another clause. Notice that using *will* in the first clause would lead to an ungrammatical/odd sentence:

> *Maybe if I'll have a read first and then we'll catch up informally later?

There's also no *will* in the  second conjunct.  Restrictions on use of *will*, of course, are a well-known aspect of the syntax of English conditional protases. Also, unlike with normal interrogative clauses, we can't swap the word *if* with the word *whether* here:

> *Maybe whether I can have a read first and then we catch up informally later?

**The question:**

1. Are there other languages which use conditional protases without a main clause to make suggestions?
2. If so, what are some example sentences?
3. Lastly, in these languages, is the word corresponding to conditional *if* (assuming there is one) also used as an interrogative word?

Comment: The _if_ and the _can_ are separately deletable: _Maybe I can have a read first and then we catch up informally later?_, or _Maybe if I have a read first and then we catch up informally later?_, or even _Maybe I have a read first and then we catch up informally later?_  Use of _will_ is irrelevant, I think.

Comment: @jlawler I was thinking more the other way round. *Maybe if I'll have a read first and then we'll catch up later* seems ungrammatical to me. Whereas *Maybe I'll have a read first and then we'll catch up later* sounds ok. So, I was thinking more that there seems to be a constraint against *will* in the *if*-string, and then using this as a diagnostic [although, as you know, I think conditional *if*-strings are in fact interrogative clauses!].  I agree with your comments - apart from the *will* bit.

Comment: @jlawler Your last example's very interesting.

Comment: Your first example sounds bad but the second sounds good, I agree. So _if_ constrains _will_ to the deontic sense, as usual, and you can't use that in a first person sg protasis. (*_If I'm willing_). My last example is parallel to the conclusion structure.

Comment: @jlawler What's the conclusion structure?

Comment: I dunno what you call it in your theory, but it's the second clause, _and then we catch  up informally later?_ It concludes the utterance; I'm not suggesting it's the Q of P implies Q. It's just the second part of the proposal.

Comment: Are you deliberately leaving out _what if_ as a different structure? “What if I have a read first and then we catch up informally later?” sounds more natural to me than any variant with _maybe_ and would be completely interchangeable with the _how about_ equivalent.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, but *what if* has a much wider range of  applications, and  some writers argue that *what if* is a single item (although I don't agree).

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote? I can't improve the question without one!